# Get the first sentence ending with . ! ? between line breaks

Tags: php, regex

Please tell me how to get the first sentence between line breaks and ending signs. ! ?
For example i have some text:

> "1)Airbus Industrie began as a consortium of European aviation firms
>   to compete with American companies such as Boeing, McDonnell Douglas,
>   and Lockheed. While many European aircraft were innovative, even the
>   most successful had small production runs.
>
> 2)In 1991, Jean Pierson, then CEO and Managing Director of Airbus
>   Industrie, described a number of factors which explained the dominant
>   position of American aircraft manufacturers.
>
> 3)The land mass of the United States made air transport the favoured
>   mode of travel; a 1942 Anglo-American agreement entrusted transport
>   aircraft production to the US; and World War II had left America with
>   a profitable, vigorous, powerful and structured aeronautical industry.
>
> 4)The retention of production and engineering assets by the partner
>   companies in effect made Airbus Industrie a sales and marketing
>   company. This arrangement led to inefficiencies due to the inherent
>   conflicts of interest that the four partner companies faced.
>
> 5)BAE Systems and EADS transferred their production assets to the new
>   company, Airbus SAS, in return for shareholdings in that company. "

You can see in the second and four paragraphs we have top and bottom line break, and the text is a sentence. But in four paragraphs we have two sentence. I need parse text where only one sentence in paragraph(for example this is second paragraphs), and when they  ending signs. ! ?

I get text between line break:

```
preg_match_all("/^[\r\n](.*)[\r\n]/m", $text, $content);
```

I know it may be simple change in `(.*)`, for example `(.*|\.|\?|\!)`, but it not work.

Comment: Edited my answer below - it's working as desired now.

Comment: Why don't you split by newline(s) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a text into sentences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377437/split-a-text-into-sentences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^([^.?!]*)/m`

It captures the entire first sentence, leaving out any ending punctuation and line breaks.

Try this. You can see a working example here: http://regex101.com/r/aK4aL3

You can see it matching the first sentence where applicable, and leaving out the rest.