# Split string using delimiter strips abbreviations

Tags: php, string, split, explode

Suppose, I want to split a string based on delimiter. So I'd simple do a `explode('. ', $myString)`. But, this strips out if there are any abbreviations present like `U.K.` or `U.S.`.

So, how could I use explode keeping all abbreviations intact.

Abbreviations will be of the form: `X.Y.Z`

While sentences would be separated by `.`
For example, `The U.S. is a country. It's in N.America.` should result in:

```
[0] = The U.S. is a country.
[1] = It's in N.America.
```

Comment: Check: preg_split("/^.\. /", "U.K. ");

Comment: @Zentoaku: Currently, I was using this only. What if one may not know how many or what kind of abbreviations are there? Any generalized solution? Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Split a text into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377437/split-a-text-into-sentences):

```
preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[A-Z])/', "The U.S. is a country. It's in N.America.")
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "The U.S. is a country."
  [1]=>
  string(18) "It's in N.America."
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. No idea why the question was down-voted by someone.